# Creating a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset as shown. I need to covert it to a timeseries data. Do suggest how to read and convert it into a time series.

```
2009-06-18 20:00:00                       [temp, x_axis, z_axis]
2009-06-18 21:00:00                       [temp, x_axis, z_axis]
2009-06-18 23:00:00                                         None
2018-09-29 19:00:00                     [status,level, temp]
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (assuming the list is your value at every time stamp):

```
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO

ss = StringIO('''
2009-06-18 20:00:00                       [temp, x_axis, z_axis]
2009-06-18 21:00:00                       [temp, x_axis, z_axis]
2009-06-18 23:00:00                                         None
2018-09-29 19:00:00                     [status,level, temp]
''')

df = pd.read_csv(ss, sep='\s+', names=['Data'])

series = df.Data
```

Output:

[image]